# Which cron file is Ezpublish using from these two CRON files

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, cron, ezpublish

Hi  i wanted to stop my crons from running in ezpublish ,

so in `/var/www/ezpublish.cron` i commented all things and restarted the cron service using

```
sudo service cron restart
```

ezpublish.cron file

```
# This must be set to the directory where eZ Publish is installed.
#EZPUBLISHROOT=/path/to/the/ez/publish/directory

# Location of the PHP Command Line Interface binary.
#PHP=/usr/local/bin/php

# Instruct cron to run the main set of cronjobs
# at 6:35am every day
#35 6 * * * cd $EZPUBLISHROOT && $PHP runcronjobs.php -q 2>&1

# Instruct cron to run the "infrequent" set of cronjobs
# at 5:20am every Monday
#20 5 * * 1 cd $EZPUBLISHROOT && $PHP runcronjobs.php -q infrequent 2>&1

# Instruct cron to run the "frequent" set of cronjobs
# every 15 minutes
#0,15,30,45 * * * * cd $EZPUBLISHROOT && $PHP runcronjobs.php -q frequent 2>&1
```

but today aslo i found that my crons are still working , so i check again and i found another cron file in

> /var/spool/cron/crontab/root

```
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.
# (/tmp/crontab.FrnXNP/crontab installed on Sun Apr  6 04:10:54 2014)
# (Cron version -- $Id: crontab.c,v 2.13 1994/01/17 03:20:37 vixie Exp $)
# This must be set to the directory where eZ Publish is installed.
EZPUBLISHROOT=/var/www

# Location of the PHP Command Line Interface binary.
PHP=/usr/bin/php

# Instruct cron to run the main set of cronjobs
# at 6:35am every day
1  * * * * cd /tmp && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily 2>&1
35 6 * * * cd $EZPUBLISHROOT && $PHP runcronjobs.php -q 2>&1

# Instruct cron to run the "infrequent" set of cronjobs
# at 5:20am every Monday
20 5 * * 1 cd $EZPUBLISHROOT && $PHP runcronjobs.php -q infrequent 2>&1

# Instruct cron to run the "frequent" set of cronjobs
# every 15 minutes
0,15,30,45 * * * * cd $EZPUBLISHROOT && $PHP runcronjobs.php -q frequent 2>&1
*/5 * * * * cd $EZPUBLISHROOT && $PHP runcronjobs.php -q frequent 2>&1
0 * * * * cd $EZPUBLISHROOT && $PHP runcronjobs.php -q videoPreview 2>&1
```

so exactly which cron file is used by Ezpublish , i am confused . Thanks you in advance

Answer (score 2):

'crontab -e' is your machine's list of cronjobs and it does not belong to ezpublish.

how cronjobs are working with ezpublish is the command you see in your list:

cd $EZPUBLISHROOT = this will navigate to the root of your ezpublish.
and then " $PHP runcronjobs.php -q frequent " will run php command line on runcronjobs.php which exists in your ezpublish's root.

"frequent" is the name of your cronjob's group of tasks which you can find it in your cronjob.ini or cronjob.ini.append.php.

you are having something like this in there: 
[CronjobPart-frequesnt]
and then all scripts which belongs to this group are run when the above command is run.
make sure they are in cronjob folder of your extension or kernel[not a recommended way at all].

you can read more [here](https://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.x/Reference/Configuration-files/cronjob.ini).

I try to explain as much as possible and maybe some of them were not needed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your issue is a cron settings issue, but not an eZPublish issue.
eZPublish can use any cron file.

Comment: I always use crontab -e as correct user, and it works !